# Using Ethernet and SD card together in SPI of arduino

Tags: arduino, ethernet, arduino-uno, spi

I am trying to use Ethernet module ENC28J60 ([http://www.amazon.com/ENC28J60-Ethernet-Network-Module-STM32/dp/B008B4QIV2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008B4QIV2)) and SD Card module in single project. I have to read data from the network and write them into the micro sd card.

How can I achieve this? I am getting following output from by sketch below

```
initialization done.
DONE Ethernet as well with IP: 255.255.255.255
```

SD card is initialized correctly, but Ethernet is not.
I have used pin 10,4 for CS of Ethernet, SD card respectively.

Program is as below

```
#include "SD.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Ethernet.h"

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,200);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,99); 
IPAddress mask(255,255,255,0); 

//File myFile;
EthernetServer server(80);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }else {
   Serial.println("initialization done.");
  }

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip,gateway,gateway,mask);
  server.begin();
  delay(5000);
  Serial.print("DONE Ethernet as well with IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());


}


void loop(){
  //todo

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare both CS pins as output. It will work.